# Fixing Height of TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create an homepage like instagram for iPhone, in the storyboard I have set the 'post cell' using a UITableViewCell and anchoring it using AutoLayout. The cell in the storyboard looks like this:

[image: Storyboard UITableViewCell]

As you can see the height is fixed to 555 pixel but when I start the simulator the cells of the UITableView don't have the height I fixed in the storyboard size inspector. It looks like this:

[image: Simulator Cells]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your code should be on Stack overflow. Thanks.

Comment: Just add height for row at indexpath delegate and set custom height in view controller. It will fix your height.

Comment: @yankitPatel thanks for your answer, what do you mean with "set custom height in view controller"?

Comment: I had posted my answer below you can check with that. @Guala

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to set fix height then you can set in controller also.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 555
    }
```

It may be Help you :)

Comment: I had tried this but It didn't work, the cell remains the same height :/

Comment: Can you show me the all delegates which you implemented ?

Comment: The delegate that I implemented for the tableView are those one: 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
    
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 555
    }

Comment: @Guala Have you set delegate and datasource  ?

Comment: I forgot to set the delegate, now it works fine! thank you so much for your help